# Flexible passing data from one object to another, is it real?

Tags: php, oop

I have two objects and I need to pass some data from one object to another. I use for that getters and setters. In the future I will have many such objects and I do not like the solution with getters and setters because I have to write too many code.

Is there a way to do this flexibly? For instance, using some maps in order to know which methods need to use to set data to another object or something like that? And yes, I write on PHP.

Comment: Could you be more detailed with what you need?

Comment: For instance, I have an object of user and DTO. DTO have properties with other names and I need manually get data from object of user and pass them in DTO.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign an object to a PHP variable, and just pass this single variable.  The properties that are publicly visible in the variable will be visible after it is passed  -- easy!

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap your copy functionality so the code stays readable.

Something like this:

```
class DataHelper {

    public static function copyData($objA, $objB) {
        $objB->setAnything( $objA->getAnything() );
    }

}

$foo = new yourClass();
$bar = new yourClass();

DataHelper::copyData($foo, $bar);
```

Further more this is "D.R.Y" according to the copy action

I know we got the usage of getters and setters in here which you wanted to prevent, but within defining data you won't repeat the getters and setter over and over again to produce your data. This will be done only once by the helper method (which of course could also be one single function not contained by a class)